# Is it possible to comment/uncomment tags inside an xml file using xmlstarlet or other bash tools

Tags: bash, shell, xmlstarlet

How can i comment/uncomment tag blocks inside an xml file programmatically using xmlstarlet or any other shell scripting libraries/tools etc.

Commenting...

Input file:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Output file:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<!-- <from>Jani</from> -->
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

---

Uncommenting...

Input file:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<!-- <from>Jani</from> -->
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Output file:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: @nahuel s answer works good at commenting but about uncommenting issue: Also '<xsl:template match="comment()"> '  and '<xsl:value-of select="."> ' woks for uncommenting but i dont want to uncomment all commented nodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing with xlstproc, i come up with a solution for uncommenting case. 
'contains' function does the trick...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <!--Identity template,
   provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <!--More specific template for "from" that provides custom behavior -->
   <xsl:template match="comment()">

       <xsl:if test='contains(.,"&lt;from&gt;")' >
           <xsl:value-of  select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
       </xsl:if>

       <xsl:if test='not (contains(.,"&lt;from&gt;"))' > 
           <xsl:copy-of select="." />
       </xsl:if>

   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

could be done with xsltproc

```
xsltproc  comment-from.xslt  input.xml
```

comment-from.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <!--Identity template,
    provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--More specific template for "from" that provides custom behavior -->
  <xsl:template match="from">
    <xsl:comment>
      <xsl:text><![CDATA[ <from>]]></xsl:text>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:text><![CDATA[</from> ]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works for commenting but uncommenting part is missing in your answer.

Comment: uncommenting is harder because comment has to be parsed and my be not valid to create nodes, otherwise if the pattern is on one line, a sed command will be simpler